# Dynamic form validation with ASP variables

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have 52 members in my database. When displayed in the admin panel, each one has a form associated with it so I can make notes for each member.

Each Member has an ID so I name each form on the page like this: `"frmRepNotes<%=MemberList("MemberID")%>"` based on the memberID from the database. This results in something like `frmRepNotes67453`. I now want to validate the form before saving the notes.

How can I use that number in the JavaScript?

```
function validate(strid)
{
     var ErrorFound = 0
     if (document.'+strid+'.taNotes.value == '')
     {
          ErrorFound = ErrorFound + 1
     }
     if (ErrorFound == 0)
     {
          document.'+strid+'.submit();
     }
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider refactoring to be something like this?

```
function validate(strid)
{     
    var ErrorFound = 0; 
    var theForm = document.getElementById("frmRepNotes"+strid);     
    if (theForm.taNotes.value == '')     
    {          
        ErrorFound +=1;     
    }     
    if (ErrorFound == 0)     
    {          
        theForm.submit();     
    }
}
```